# Can't compile minimal document class?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to compile a gnuplot epslatex output (which contains a .tex and .eps file). When I use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\input{temp.tex}
\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
) (C:\Users\Stefan\Documents\temp.tex

 ! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2 \documentclass
              {minimal}
?
```

The temp.tex file output by gnuplot has documentclass{minimal}, so my document can't run minimal classes for some reason, why is that?

Comment: You can not `\input` a complecte TeX file with `\documentclass`

Comment: You must either use `set terminal epslatex standalone` and compile the resulting document, or use only `set terminal epslatex` and then you can include the image file with `\input{myimage}` in an other document.